# Google Cardboard Screenshot of VrPanoramaView

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, google-cardboard, panoramas

Is it possible to capture a Screenshot of the current field of view in a Google Cardboard VrPanoramaView?  I've tried both when it's in Cardboard view and when it's in the simple panorama widget.  I've seen the posts about creating a BitMap from View.getDrawingCache(), but for the PanoramaView, the BitMap is empty, and for every View layer going up, it just returns a lot of black.

What I'm trying to do is an image recognition project that captures an image of whatever the current thing is the user is looking at, then sends it off to a machine learning system to try and figure out what they are looking at.

I've looked a little into the OpenGL stuff for the GvrView path, but I've not been able to find how to represent the panorama image using the OpenGL rendering system, not to mention I've got little to no exposure to OpenGL in the first place.

At this point, I'd even settle for the figuring out how to invoke the system screenshot you get when holding the appropriate buttons, as long as I can do it programatically.

One other interesting thing to mention that I've found:  The height of the VrPanoramaView appears to be 0.  All the height settings for the view show a height of zero:

`Activity Main Layout dimensions: 2560 x 1440
Linear Layout dimensions: 2432 x 1312
VrPanoramaView dimensions: 2432 x 0`

Maybe there are some child elements that are actually doing the visualization here in the Renderer, but I can't get to them, and the PanoramaView does not any child views.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the VrPanoramaView's Display has the FLAG_SECURE display flag set. From the docs: Indicates that the display has a secure video output and supports compositing secure surfaces.

I'll edit if I find a workaround / reason for this.

-Tom

Comment: Did you find any solution?